# Get entity by field value in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have used a method like this before to retrieve the entity and It was working perfectly in **ASP.NET Core 2.2** Repository (because most of my tables have the **CODE** property):

```
public T GetByCode(string code)
{
      PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty("Code");
      return _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(t => pi.GetValue(t).ToString().Trim().ToLower() == code.Trim().ToLower());
}
```

But as soon as I changed the framework to *.NET Core 3.1* I got error like:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet .Where(c
>   => __pi_0.GetValue(c).ToString().Trim().ToLower() == __ToLower_1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can
>   be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting
>   a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync().

Comment: so error tells you what  is the issue and what to do. What is the question?

Comment: This is a part of question, I don't know how to rewrite the query to AsEnumerable() and the rest

Comment: @fenixil: thats bad advise since the `where` would be evaluated in memory; hence; fetching the whole data set first. So your "comment" only helps in a small subset of use cases.

Comment: @Mertez: if your dataset is small enough use "ToListAsync" before the where. If not; google for which string transformations can be transformed to SQL. There are many; the ones you have there as well, but the syntax is different. Also note: string comparisation in SQL is often case invariant.

Comment: I found a question like mine but not the exact answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074925/913608) by @daniel-hilgarth

Comment: @Stefan It's a huge table

Comment: @Stefan, how ` rewrite the query in a form that can be translated` become a bad advice? Even with `AsEnumerable()` it will work exactly the same way it did in Core 2.2. My advice to read the error is not bad at all :)

Comment: @Mertez  in your question I see statement that `It was working __perfectly__ in ASP.NET Core 2.2` (what is actually far from __perfectly__ as you might already understand) and a statement that you got the error when upgraded. Nothing like `how to rewrite the query to AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @Mertez besides the solution which you get already, I'd strongly recommend you take some time and read more about EF. I can recommend [official MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/overview) and [these tutorials](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/basics/how-entity-framework-works.aspx). After you read them, you will feel yourself much more comfortable.

Comment: @fenixil: yes, but the thing is; the table is huge. The `AsEnumerable` will drag it completely into memory.

Answer (score 2):

Because in EF Core 2.2, you were probably fetching the entire table into memory.

In your case, since all these tables have a `Code` property, I would recommend adding some form of `IHaveCode` common interface. Then you can trivially remove all the reflection, which EF Core can't translate to sql;

```cs
public T GetByCode<T>(string code) where T:IHaveCode
{
      return _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Code.Trim().ToLower() == code.Trim().ToLower());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jeremy-lakeman What this interface "IHaveCode" look like?

Comment: I just mean that whatever common properties you have on these types should be represented by either a common base type, or interface. eg `interface ICommon{ string Code { get; set; }}`. What you call it, or what you include is up to you.

Comment: I already have a base class, the Id and Code came from the base class

Comment: @Mertez: try to google the conversions; I dont know them from the top of my head but if you use a variant of `System.Convert` is might translate in correct SQL. There is a list, but since I am on mobile, I dont have the chance to search it.

Comment: So you could just `where T:BaseClass`