# aggregation count in linq query returns null

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 project. In my controller I have a linq query like the following and without defining inprocessapicount and pendingcount which claculates counts of related amounts, it works fine but after adding them to applicants query in select part, applicants returns null and the error is: .Count(a => a.requestStatus == "bb") could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync() . I appreciate if anyone suggests me a solution.

```
 var applicants = (from t1 in _context.VwDesk
                              
                              let tg = new {
     
                                   itemID = t1.ItemId,
                                   applicantID = t1.ApplicantId,
                                   applicantName = t1.ApplicantName,
                                 
                                   gateName =t1.GateName,

                                   requestStatus = t1.LastReqStatus
                               }
                               group tg by new { tg.requestStatus,tg.itemID ,tg.applicantID, tg.applicantName} into ApiAppGp
                               select new
                               {
                                   applicantName = ApiAppGp.Key.applicantName,

                                   itemname = ApiAppGp.Key.itemID,
 
                                   itemcount =ApiAppGp.Count(),

                                   inprocessapicount = ApiAppGp.Where(a => a.requestStatus == "bb").Count(),
                                   pendingapicount = ApiAppGp.Where(a => a.requestStatus == "aa").Count()


                               }).ToList();
```

What I want is: There are some applicants in Database and each applicant may have multiple or zero requests. (Each applicant orders multiple or zero itemID) each one of those applicants needs to get some item (itemID) and each of those item has requeststatus =="aa" or requeststatus =="bb" or none of them which the status in that case is "general". Now I want to understand, how many each applicant's itemID has requeststatus=="aa" and how many each applicant's itemID has requeststatus=="bb" according to all ItemId they have ordered.

Comment: "after adding them to my query in select part" - can you show the code that is failing, not the code that is working?

Answer (score 0):

Try combining `Where` and `Count` methods, because `Count` has also Lambda version:

```cs
inprocessapicount = ApiAppGp.Count(a => a.requestStatus == "bb"),
pendingapicount = ApiAppGp.Count(a => a.requestStatus == "aa")
```

Otherwise, I don't see any problem in your code, unless the `GroupBy` statement actually can find any element to Group(empty collection).
Try also running the same result without the initial `select` statement(before `group by`).

Comment: I wrote like what you suggested but still count() returns null. The error is: .Count(a => a.requestStatus == "bb") could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074844/ef-linq-error-after-change-from-dotnet-core-2-2-6-to-3-0-0) as a good explanation for the issue above. 
What I can suggest here is to call `ToList()` after `GroupBy` and only after that call for `Select` statement.

Comment: I think the problem is sometimes there is no a => a.requestStatus == "bb" or a => a.requestStatus == "aa" matched condition thus they returns null. But I don't know how I can fix the issue.

Comment: @MinaMRM if there is no matching that shouldn't return null but 0. Try using `?` operator before accessing to `requestStatus`, like `a?.requestStatus == "bb"`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. when I add ? to the expression, it shows me error.

Comment: Is it possible count() doesn't work on View? because I'm calculation count on view data.

Comment: @MinaMRM I meant this way: `ApiAppGp.Count(a => a?.requestStatus == "bb")`. If that doesn't work check this: `ApiAppGp.Where(a =>a.requestStatus != null).Count(a => a?.requestStatus == "bb")`. Btw, if you are getting stuck in all this logic try counting `requestStatus` outside of your main query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still got stock and I did what you suggested to me but it shows me the error an expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator

Comment: But how can I count request status for each applicant outside of my main query?

Comment: Just move outside of your group statement `inprocessapicount` and  `pendingapicount` properties. Later calculate them in a separate code.