# Compare between DateTime from Client and DateTime Saved in Database

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to make a comparison between two Dates in Date,Hours,Minutes,Seconds but when I invoke
x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay the nullable exception appeared.

I thought this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074844/ef-linq-error-after-change-from-dotnet-core-2-2-6-to-3-0-0) answer will solve my problem but after I fellow the solution the problem still appread
Here is my query :

```
public async Task<List<MessageDto>> getMessageHistory(long userId, string code, long HCSId, long Role,DateTime latestMessageDateTime , DateTime messageDateBeforeSeeMore)
        {
var result =await _repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.listOfMessages)
                                       .Where(x => ((x.receiverID == userId|| x.CreatorUserId == userId)
                                       && x.code== code) && (
                                        x.CreationTime != null
                                        
                                       && x.CreationTime.Date > latestMessageDateTime.Date
                                       && x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay !=null 
                                       
                                       && x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.Hours > latestMessageDateTime.TimeOfDay.Hours /*<===== this cause the problem if I remove it the query working fine*/

                                       )
                                       && x.listOfMessages.Any(x => x.HCSId== HCSId)

                                       ).OrderBy(message => message.CreationTime).ToListAsync();

return result ;
}
```

**Update:**

the Exception details :

```
-       $exception  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.NullReferenceException


+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}


  at MyProject.ChatAppService.MessageAppService.<getMessageHistory>d__19.MoveNext() in D:\WorkSpace\MyProject\aspnet-core\src\MyProject.Application\ChatAppService\MessageAppService.cs:line 346

+       TargetSite  {Void MoveNext()}   System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
```

**Update 2:**
I follow the steps that have been mentioned by @RandRandom

and what I found is below Exception

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Message>
    .Where(m => m.receiverID == __citizenId_0 || m.CreatorUserId == __userId_0 && m.code == __code_1 && DbSet<HCSMessages>
        .Where(h => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(m, "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(m, "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(h, "messageId"))
        .Any(h => h.HCsId == __HCSId_2) && m.CreationTime > __messageDateBeforeSeeMore_3)
    .Where(m => m.CreationTime.Date > __latestMessageDateTime_Date_4)
    .Where(m => m.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.Hours > __latestMessageDateTime_TimeOfDay_Hours_5)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: I kind of doubt what you are saying is correct, because `DateTime` and `TimOfDay` are both structs and can't be null, so you shouldn't see a `NullReferenceException`. If one of them would be declared as `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?`, you could get a `NullReferenceException` but that isn't the case. Can you provide full details of the Exception, message and stacktrace would be nice.

Comment: @RandRandom I'm trying the mentioned solution and I want to provide your additional enogh and clear details !

Comment: @RandRandom You can check the exception details now.

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry for the late response, had some holidays.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**

The exception didn't have an inner exception with more usefull information?

**Attempt of an answer:**

A wild guess would be, the only thing that actually can be null at all is `x.listOfMessages` since it is the only reference type you are using, everything else is a struct.

You can "easily" narrow the error down, by spliting your query into multiple parts and materialize each query seperatly one after the other.

So first rewrite your query like this:

```
public async Task<List<MessageDto>> getMessageHistory(long userId, string code, long HCSId, long Role,DateTime latestMessageDateTime , DateTime messageDateBeforeSeeMore)
{
    IEnumerable<MessageDto> result = await _repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.listOfMessages);
    
    result = result.Where(x => x.receiverID == userId || x.CreatorUserId == userId);
    result = result.Where(x => x.code == code);

    //dropped the null checks for DateTime and TimeOfDay, since NULL should be impossible
    result = result.Where(x => x.CreationTime.Date > latestMessageDateTime.Date );
    result = result.Where(x => x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.Hours > latestMessageDateTime.TimeOfDay.Hours);
    
    result = result.Where(x => x.listOfMessages.Any(x => x.HCSId== HCSId));
    
    result = result.OrderBy(message => message.CreationTime);
    
    return (List<MessageDto>)result;
}
```

After this add `.ToListAsync()` on each line beginning at the top and moving it with each successfull step one place further down.

So on your first test change the first line to this:

```
IEnumerable<MessageDto> result = await _repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.listOfMessages).ToListAsync(); //added .ToListAsync()
```

For the second test remove the `ToListAsync()` from the first line and add it to the second line, first and second line should than look like this:

```
IEnumerable<MessageDto> result = await _repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.listOfMessages);  //removed .ToListAsync()
result = result.Where(x => (x.receiverID == userId || x.CreatorUserId == userId)).ToListAsync(); //added .ToListAsync()
```

With this approach your are materializing each condidition seperatly and can figure out what condition will fail.

**Edit:**

The error in "Update2" happens because you are doing something that can't be translated into a SQL query.

To fix this in general you have two options

1. Run the unsupported expression locally, there for skip the necessety to translate the expression to SQL

   To do this you have to evaluate all expressions prior to the unsupported, the evalution happens when an enumeration on the `IQueryable` happens, easy ways to do this are for example to call `ToList()`, `ToArray()` or `AsEnumerable()`, after this your expression will run against an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an `IQueryable<T>`
2. Use DbFunctions if a suiting one is available - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions - or write your own functions - https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/add-custom-database-functions-for-entity-framework-core

But in your case I would question your expressions at a whole, why are comparing the date and hours seperatly

```
    result = result.Where(x => x.CreationTime.Date > latestMessageDateTime.Date );
    result = result.Where(x => x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.Hours > latestMessageDateTime.TimeOfDay.Hours);
```

Instead of just simple comparing the `DateTime` struct?

```
    result = result.Where(x => x.CreationTime > latestMessageDateTime );
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beggining I will try to put the query parameters (date from client) outside the query and get concrete values.
For example

```
int lastMessageHours = latestMessageDateTime.TimeOfDay.Hours;
DateTime lastMessageDate = latestMessageDateTime.Date;
```

And then pass it to query

```
var result =await _repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.listOfMessages)
                                   .Where(x => ((x.receiverID == userId|| x.CreatorUserId == userId)
                                   && x.code== code) && (
                                    x.CreationTime != null
                                    
                                   && x.CreationTime.Date > lastMessageDate
                                   && x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay !=null 
                                   
                                   && x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.Hours > latestMessageHours

                                   )
                                   && x.listOfMessages.Any(x => x.HCSId== HCSId)

                                   ).OrderBy(message => message.CreationTime).ToListAsync();
```

If this does not help CreationTime has value if it is nullable type.

```
x.CreationTime.HasValue
```

I also suggest to split this query between multiple methods. Write extension method for this query:

```
public static IQueryable<Message> NewerThan(this IQueryable<Message> query, DateTime value)
{
int lastMessageHours = latestMessageDateTime.TimeOfDay.Hours;
DateTime lastMessageDate = latestMessageDateTime.Date;
return query.Where(x=> x.CreationTime != null

                               && x.CreationTime.Date > lastMessageDate
                               && x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay !=null 

                               && x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.Hours > latestMessageHours );
}
```

Query will be more readable.

Comment: the mentioned solution not work and both of values not Nullable!

Comment: Is there any difference if you compare DateTime using  x.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.Hours or x.CreationTime.Hours? I think both should returns the same value. I've just analyze sql server function mapping and there are no TimeOfDay.Hours mapping to any function. This is a link to analyzed source code https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/2352499b52cdfc95ddcfd81c4967e12512e00eee/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Query/Internal/SqlServerDateTimeMemberTranslator.cs