# LINQ error after upgrading .netcore 2.2 to .NET 5

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

after upgrading from .netCore 2.2 to .NET 5, i receive the following error:

> The LINQ expression 'e' could not be translated. Either rewrite the
> query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable',
> 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Here is my code:

```cs
var query =
    (from cf in ctx.CotacoesFornecedores.IgnoreQueryFilters().AsNoTracking()
        join f in ctx.Fornecedores.IgnoreQueryFilters().AsNoTracking() on cf.FornecedorId equals f.Id
        join pj in ctx.PessoasJuridicas.IgnoreQueryFilters().AsNoTracking() on f.ParceiroId equals pj.ParceiroId
        join c in ctx.Cotacoes.IgnoreQueryFilters().AsNoTracking() on cf.CotacaoId equals c.Id
        where filtro.Fornecedores.Contains(cf.FornecedorId)
        && c.EmpresaId == idEmpresa
        && c.Status == Models.StatusCotacao.Liberada.Id
        && codigoStatus.Contains(cf.Status)
        && (!apenasVigentes || (apenasVigentes && c.DataInicial <= dataAtual && c.DataFinal >= dataAtual))
        orderby c.Numero, c.DataInicial
        select new
        {
            c.Id,
            IdCotacaoFornecedor = cf.Id,
            pj.Cnpj,
            pj.NomeFantasia,
            pj.RazaoSocial,
            c.Numero,
            c.DataInicial,
            c.DataFinal,
            cf.Status,
            cf.FornecedorId,
            cf.PermiteAlterarQuantidadeEmbalagem,
            c.Observacoes
        });

if (filtro.Id > 0)
    query = query.Where(q => q.Id == filtro.Id);

if (filtro.Numero > 0)
    query = query.Where(q => q.Numero == filtro.Numero);

if (filtro.DataInicial.GetValueOrDefault() > DateTime.MinValue)
    query = query.Where(q => q.DataInicial.Date >= filtro.DataInicial.Value.Date);

if (filtro.DataFinal.GetValueOrDefault() > DateTime.MinValue)
    query = query.Where(q => q.DataFinal.Value.Date <= filtro.DataFinal.Value.Date);

return query
    .Select(q => new Models.CotacaoFornecedor
    {
        Id = q.Id,
        Numero = q.Numero,
        IdFornecedor = q.FornecedorId,
        IdCotacaoFornecedor = q.IdCotacaoFornecedor,
        CnpjFornecedor = q.Cnpj,
        NomeFantasiaFornecedor = q.NomeFantasia,
        RazaoSocialFornecedor = q.RazaoSocial,
        DataInicial = q.DataInicial,
        DataFinal = q.DataFinal,
        Status = Models.StatusCotacaoFornecedor.List().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == q.Status),
        PermiteAlterarQuantidadeEmbalagem = q.PermiteAlterarQuantidadeEmbalagem,
        Observacoes = q.Observacoes
    }).ToPagedList(filtro);
```

The error points to the end on **Status = Models.StatusCotacaoFornecedor.List().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == q.Status),**

I understand that is not possible anymore to have client side evaluation, but i dont know the best solution to make it work without breaking the code logic, any suggestions?

Comment: It is possible to have client side evaluation by calling `AsEnumberable` in corresponding place.

Comment: What `ToPagedList` does?

Comment: Just notice `.IgnoreQueryFilters().AsNoTracking()` need only once per whole query. Add them on the end.

Comment: Comment out `Status = Models.StatusCotacaoFornecedor.List().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == q.Status),` looks like it is a problem.

Comment: Please read the error message. It **does not** say that you cannot use client-side evaluation. It **does** say that you have to implicitly opt into doing so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Linq Error after change from dotnet Core 2.2.6 to 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074844/ef-linq-error-after-change-from-dotnet-core-2-2-6-to-3-0-0)

Answer (score 1):

Separate client-side logic from server-side. It is not easy to deduce that your query needs postprocessing automatically

```cs
var pagedList =
    .Select(q => new Models.CotacaoFornecedor
    {
        Id = q.Id,
        Numero = q.Numero,
        IdFornecedor = q.FornecedorId,
        IdCotacaoFornecedor = q.IdCotacaoFornecedor,
        CnpjFornecedor = q.Cnpj,
        NomeFantasiaFornecedor = q.NomeFantasia,
        RazaoSocialFornecedor = q.RazaoSocial,
        DataInicial = q.DataInicial,
        DataFinal = q.DataFinal,
        PermiteAlterarQuantidadeEmbalagem = q.PermiteAlterarQuantidadeEmbalagem,
        Observacoes = q.Observacoes
    }).ToPagedList(filtro);

foreach (var q in pagedList)
{
   q.Status = Models.StatusCotacaoFornecedor.List().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == q.Status);
}

return pagedList;
```

Answer (score -2):

adding .AsEnumberable resolved my problem.

Comment: this is a bad idea - that means it eagerly pulls records

Comment: Probably fine if he put it on the line where the error is. There where already a bajillion filters before it. It just means it will return (potentially) unnessesary colums and he does the mapping to the model afterwards. Not that he will select the entier database table.

Comment: It's not resolving is a future problem.