# The query that works under Entity Framework 6 does not work in .Net5

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a problem with a query not working under .Net5 I am not sure why a query that works well under Entity Framework 6 does not get a list of standards in .Net5. What do you need to do to start working on Core?

```
 var listModel =
                (
                from dane in _dbContext.Standard
                join kraj in _dbContext.CountryStandard
                on dane.IdCountryStandard equals kraj.IdCountryStandard
                join opcja in _dbContext.MeasureDiameterOption
                on dane.IdStandard equals opcja.IdStandard
                join metoda in _dbContext.MeasureDiameterMethod
                on opcja.IdMeasureDiameterMethod equals metoda.IdMeasureDiameterMethod
                join sposob in _dbContext.WalkingLineRadius
                on opcja.IdWalkingLineRadius equals sposob.IdWalkingLineRadius
                
                select new StandardEnt()
                {
                    IdStandard = dane.IdStandard,
                    IdCountryStandard = dane.IdCountryStandard,
                    StandardName = dane.StandardName,
                    IsActive = dane.IsActive,
                    NameCountry = kraj.NameCountryStandard,
                    FreeHeadSpace = (double)dane.FreeHeadSpace,
                    IsTlcStandard = dane.IsTlcStandard,
                    MinLandingSize = (double)dane.MinLandingSize,
                    MinStepHeight = (double)dane.MinStepHeight,
                    MaxStepHeight = (double)dane.MaxStepHeight,
                    MinConvinience = (double)dane.MinConvinience,
                    MaxConvinience = (double)dane.MaxConvinience,
                    MaxStepDeep = (double)dane.MaxStepDeep,
                    MinStepDeep = (double)dane.MinStepDeep,
                    MaxStepWidth = (double)dane.MaxStepWidth,
                    WidthLimit = (double)dane.WidthLimit,
                    StartOverlap = (double)dane.StartOverlap,
                    InternalHandrailMaxRadius = (double)dane.InternalHandrailMaxRadius,
                    PrimaryCalcMethod = (from metody in _dbContext.MeasureDiameterOption
                                         select new MeasureDiameterMethodEnt()
                                         {
                                             IdStandard = metody.IdStandard,
                                             IdMeasureDiameterOption = metody.IdMeasureDiameterOption,
                                             Description = metody.Description,
                                             IdMeasureDiameterMethod = metody.IdMeasureDiameterMethod,
                                             IdWalkingLineRadius = metody.IdWalkingLineRadius,
                                             IdCalcMethodType = metody.WalkingLineRadius.CalcMethodType.IdCalcMethodType,
                                             IdWalkingLineMeasure = metody.WalkingLineRadius.WalkingLineMeasure.IdWalkingLineMeasure,
                                             //CalcMethod = Enum.Parse<DiamDivide>(opcja.WalkingLineRadius.CalcMethodType.CalcMethodNameType),
                                             //WalkingLineMeasure = Enum.Parse<WalkingLineMeasureMethod>(opcja.WalkingLineRadius.WalkingLineMeasure.WalkingLineMeasureName),
                                             CalcMethodName = metody.MeasureDiameterMethod.CalcMethodName,
                                             CalcMethodNameType = metody.WalkingLineRadius.CalcMethodType.CalcMethodNameType,
                                             WalkingLineMeasureName = metody.WalkingLineRadius.WalkingLineMeasure.WalkingLineMeasureName,
                                             FirstWidth = (double)metody.WalkingLineRadius.FirstWidth,
                                             SecondWidth = (double)metody.WalkingLineRadius.SecondWidth
                                         }).Where(s => s.CalcMethodName == "PrimaryCalcMethod" && s.IdStandard == dane.IdStandard).FirstOrDefault(),
                    SecondaryCalcMethod = (from metody in _dbContext.MeasureDiameterOption
                                           select new MeasureDiameterMethodEnt()
                                           {
                                               IdStandard = metody.IdStandard,
                                               IdMeasureDiameterOption = metody.IdMeasureDiameterOption,
                                               Description = metody.Description,
                                               IdMeasureDiameterMethod = metody.IdMeasureDiameterMethod,
                                               IdWalkingLineRadius = metody.IdWalkingLineRadius,
                                               IdCalcMethodType = metody.WalkingLineRadius.CalcMethodType.IdCalcMethodType,
                                               IdWalkingLineMeasure = metody.WalkingLineRadius.WalkingLineMeasure.IdWalkingLineMeasure,
                                               //CalcMethod = Enum.Parse<DiamDivide>(opcja.WalkingLineRadius.CalcMethodType.CalcMethodNameType),
                                               //WalkingLineMeasure = Enum.Parse<WalkingLineMeasureMethod>(opcja.WalkingLineRadius.WalkingLineMeasure.WalkingLineMeasureName),
                                               CalcMethodName = metody.MeasureDiameterMethod.CalcMethodName,
                                               CalcMethodNameType = metody.WalkingLineRadius.CalcMethodType.CalcMethodNameType,
                                               WalkingLineMeasureName = metody.WalkingLineRadius.WalkingLineMeasure.WalkingLineMeasureName,
                                               FirstWidth = (double)metody.WalkingLineRadius.FirstWidth,
                                               SecondWidth = (double)metody.WalkingLineRadius.SecondWidth
                                           }).Where(s => s.CalcMethodName == "SecondaryCalcMethod" && s.IdStandard == dane.IdStandard).FirstOrDefault()
                                           
                }
            ).GroupBy(x => x.IdStandard).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
            return  listModel;
```

And error massage.

> The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector:
> s.IdStandard, ElementSelector:new StandardEnt{ IdStandard =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 0, IdCountryStandard =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 1, StandardName =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 2, IsActive =
> (bool)ProjectionBindingExpression: 3, NameCountry =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 4, FreeHeadSpace =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 5, IsTlcStandard =
> (bool)ProjectionBindingExpression: 6, MinLandingSize =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 7, MinStepHeight =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 8, MaxStepHeight =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 9, MinConvinience =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 10, MaxConvinience =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 11, MaxStepDeep =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 12, MinStepDeep =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 13, MaxStepWidth =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 14, WidthLimit =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 15, StartOverlap =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 16, InternalHandrailMaxRadius =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 17, PrimaryCalcMethod =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 30 == default(Nullable) ?
> default(MeasureDiameterMethodEnt) : new MeasureDiameterMethodEnt{
> IdStandard = ProjectionBindingExpression: 18, IdMeasureDiameterOption
> = (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 19, Description = ProjectionBindingExpression: 20, IdMeasureDiameterMethod =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 21, IdWalkingLineRadius =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 22, IdCalcMethodType =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 23, IdWalkingLineMeasure =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 24, CalcMethodName =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 25, CalcMethodNameType =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 26, WalkingLineMeasureName =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 27, FirstWidth =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 28, SecondWidth =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 29 } , SecondaryCalcMethod =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 43 == default(Nullable) ?
> default(MeasureDiameterMethodEnt) : new MeasureDiameterMethodEnt{
> IdStandard = ProjectionBindingExpression: 31, IdMeasureDiameterOption
> = (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 32, Description = ProjectionBindingExpression: 33, IdMeasureDiameterMethod =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 34, IdWalkingLineRadius =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 35, IdCalcMethodType =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 36, IdWalkingLineMeasure =
> (int)ProjectionBindingExpression: 37, CalcMethodName =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 38, CalcMethodNameType =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 39, WalkingLineMeasureName =
> ProjectionBindingExpression: 40, FirstWidth =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 41, SecondWidth =
> (double)ProjectionBindingExpression: 42 } } .FirstOrDefault()' could
> not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

Comment: I using .NET5 in project

Comment: If you separate the subqueries `PrimaryCalcMethod` and `SecondaryCalcMethod` into separate expressions then it should become easier to debug. It should become easier to identify what became a problem when `s.IdStandard` is being referred to in the group-by method at the end of your query. Also, for comprehension, it might be easier to rewrite the query completely in query syntax or completely in method syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Linq Error after change from dotnet Core 2.2.6 to 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074844/ef-linq-error-after-change-from-dotnet-core-2-2-6-to-3-0-0)

Comment: @GSerg Did EF6 have client side evaluation?

Comment: A much better option is to replace all joins and subqueries by navigation properties. Then the query will look far less impressive and, the best part, it won't require grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here that after `GroupBy` you cannot access to grouped items. Only Key and Aggregation result is available. It is strict SQL limitation and there is no silver bullet to cover all cases when translating LINQ query.

I have refactored your query to be translatable but it is kind of workaround because SQL Server has to do a little bit more calculations.

Helper method for making projection:

```cs
public static IQueryable<MeasureDiameterMethodEnt> Project(IQueryable<MeasureDiameterOption> query)
{
    return query.Select(metody => new MeasureDiameterMethodEnt
        {
            IdStandard = metody.IdStandard,
            IdMeasureDiameterOption = metody.IdMeasureDiameterOption,
            Description = metody.Description,
            IdMeasureDiameterMethod = metody.IdMeasureDiameterMethod,
            IdWalkingLineRadius = metody.IdWalkingLineRadius,
            IdCalcMethodType = metody.WalkingLineRadius.CalcMethodType.IdCalcMethodType,
            IdWalkingLineMeasure = metody.WalkingLineRadius.WalkingLineMeasure.IdWalkingLineMeasure,
            //CalcMethod = Enum.Parse<DiamDivide>(opcja.WalkingLineRadius.CalcMethodType.CalcMethodNameType),
            //WalkingLineMeasure = Enum.Parse<WalkingLineMeasureMethod>(opcja.WalkingLineRadius.WalkingLineMeasure.WalkingLineMeasureName),
            CalcMethodName = metody.MeasureDiameterMethod.CalcMethodName,
            CalcMethodNameType = metody.WalkingLineRadius.CalcMethodType.CalcMethodNameType,
            WalkingLineMeasureName = metody.WalkingLineRadius.WalkingLineMeasure.WalkingLineMeasureName,
            FirstWidth = (double)metody.WalkingLineRadius.FirstWidth,
            SecondWidth = (double)metody.WalkingLineRadius.SecondWidth
        }
    );
}
```

And final query:

```cs
var notGrouped =
    from dane in _dbContext.Standard
    join kraj in _dbContext.CountryStandard
    on dane.IdCountryStandard equals kraj.IdCountryStandard
    join opcja in _dbContext.MeasureDiameterOption
    on dane.IdStandard equals opcja.IdStandard
    join metoda in _dbContext.MeasureDiameterMethod
    on opcja.IdMeasureDiameterMethod equals metoda.IdMeasureDiameterMethod
    join sposob in _dbContext.WalkingLineRadius
    on opcja.IdWalkingLineRadius equals sposob.IdWalkingLineRadius
    
    select new
    {
        IdStandard = dane.IdStandard,
        IdCountryStandard = dane.IdCountryStandard,
        StandardName = dane.StandardName,
        IsActive = dane.IsActive,
        NameCountry = kraj.NameCountryStandard,
        FreeHeadSpace = (double)dane.FreeHeadSpace,
        IsTlcStandard = dane.IsTlcStandard,
        MinLandingSize = (double)dane.MinLandingSize,
        MinStepHeight = (double)dane.MinStepHeight,
        MaxStepHeight = (double)dane.MaxStepHeight,
        MinConvinience = (double)dane.MinConvinience,
        MaxConvinience = (double)dane.MaxConvinience,
        MaxStepDeep = (double)dane.MaxStepDeep,
        MinStepDeep = (double)dane.MinStepDeep,
        MaxStepWidth = (double)dane.MaxStepWidth,
        WidthLimit = (double)dane.WidthLimit,
        StartOverlap = (double)dane.StartOverlap,
        InternalHandrailMaxRadius = (double)dane.InternalHandrailMaxRadius                                
    };

var firstEntryQuery = 
    from u in notGrouped.Select(x => new { x.IdStandard }).Distinct()
    from q in notGrouped.Where(q => q.IdStandard == u.IdStandard).Take(1)
    from primary in Project(_dbContext.MeasureDiameterOption)
        .Where(s => s.CalcMethodName == "PrimaryCalcMethod" && s.IdStandard == q.IdStandard)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfempty()
    from secondary in Project(_dbContext.MeasureDiameterOption)
        .Where(s => s.CalcMethodName == "SecondaryCalcMethod" && s.IdStandard == q.IdStandard)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfempty()
    select new StandardEnt
    {
        IdStandard = q.IdStandard,
        IdCountryStandard = q.IdCountryStandard,
        StandardName = q.StandardName,
        IsActive = q.IsActive,
        NameCountry = q.NameCountry,
        FreeHeadSpace = q.FreeHeadSpace,
        IsTlcStandard = q.IsTlcStandard,
        MinLandingSize = q.MinLandingSize,
        MinStepHeight = q.MinStepHeight,
        MaxStepHeight = q.MaxStepHeight,
        MinConvinience = q.MinConvinience,
        MaxConvinience = q.MaxConvinience,
        MaxStepDeep = q.MaxStepDeep,
        MinStepDeep = q.MinStepDeep,
        MaxStepWidth = q.MaxStepWidth,
        WidthLimit = q.WidthLimit,
        StartOverlap = q.StartOverlap,
        InternalHandrailMaxRadius = q.InternalHandrailMaxRadius,

        PrimaryCalcMethod = primary,
        SecondaryCalcMethod = secondary             
    };
```