# LINQ Entity Framework query not working in EF Core, throwing exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this Entity Framework v4.0 Query that works in the old app and I am converting it to EF Core version 5.0.

When I run the code in debug, it throws the following error after the .ToList();

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>()
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: DbSet<Address>(), 
        outerKeySelector: u => u.UserId, 
        innerKeySelector: a => a.UserId, 
        resultSelector: (u, ua) => new { 
            u = u, 
            ua = ua
         })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

So, I added the .ToList() and also tried .ToListAsync() to the end of the query but this error still exists.

I looked at docs.microsoft and found this example it looks like my query

```
  var query = from person in people
                join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { person.FirstName, PetName = subpet?.Name ?? String.Empty };
```

UPDATE: I commented out the join and that removed the error but no clue why that should not work. Another post mentions that this error is generated if the linq can't be interpretated but the additional join looks simple, right?

```
 var users =
    
                        (from u in this.MyDbContext.User
                         join a in this.MyDbContext.Address
                                     on u.UserId equals a.UserId
                                     into ua
                         //join d in this.MyDbContext.JobTitle
                         //          on e.JobTitleId equals d.JobTitleId
                         from ua_left in ua.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new UserViewModel
                         {
                             BoardId = u.BoardId,
                             UserId = u.UserId,
                             LastName = u.LastName,
                             FirstName = u.FirstName,
                             JobTitleId = u.JobTitleId,
                             //JobTitle = d.JobTitleDescription,
                             Email = u.Email,
                             Grade = u.Grade,
                             Title = u.Title,
                             //StartDate = ua_left.StartDate,
                         });
  
      var test = users.ToList();
```

I am not sure what I am missing

```
var users =

                    (from u in this.MyDbContext.User
                     join a in this.MyDbContext.Address
                                 on u.UserId equals a.UserId
                                 into ua
                     join d in this.MyDbContext.JobTitle
                                 on e.JobTitleId equals d.JobTitleId
                     from ua_left in ua.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new UserViewModel
                     {
                         BoardId = u.BoardId,
                         UserId = u.UserId,
                         LastName = u.LastName,
                         FirstName = u.FirstName,
                         JobTitleId = u.JobTitleId,
                         JobTitle = d.JobTitleDescription,
                         Email = u.Email,
                         Grade = u.Grade,
                         Title = u.Title,
                         //StartDate = ua_left.StartDate,
                     });



  var test = users.ToList();
```

After playing withg the code, the query will run and return data if I take out the left join clause like so

```
var users =

                    (from u in this.MyDbContext.User
                     join a in this.MyDbContext.Address
                                 on u.UserId equals a.UserId
                     join d in this.MyDbContext.JobTitle
                                 on e.JobTitleId equals d.JobTitleId
                     select new UserViewModel
                     {
                         BoardId = u.BoardId,
                         UserId = u.UserId,
                         LastName = u.LastName,
                         FirstName = u.FirstName,
                         JobTitleId = u.JobTitleId,
                         JobTitle = d.JobTitleDescription,
                         Email = u.Email,
                         Grade = u.Grade,
                         Title = u.Title,
                         //StartDate = ua_left.StartDate,
                     });



  var test = users.ToList();
```

I looked at another post, others are using the same left join. I am not sure why it is not working on EF Core.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please also mention the EF Core version you used.

Comment: Is your StartDate property of UserViewModel is nullable? If not, try to make it nullable and execute the query.

Comment: I'd imagine you're using EF Core 3+. Although not directly related, I believe it is the cause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074844/ef-linq-error-after-change-from-dotnet-core-2-2-6-to-3-0-0  - basically, query evaluation is no longer done client-side. if a method can not be converted to a SQL (or other) command then it throws. If you want to accept this as an answer then let me know and I'll add it (it looks like it's the `DefaultIfEmpty` that can't be translated - you can load the first part into memory then try again)

Comment: What is `e` in your query?

Comment: I commented out one of the join and the error went away but not sure why?

Comment: After edit: Hmm, strange. I wonder if it's because there's a `DateTime` of which the minimum value can not be translated to SQL. Is it possible to change the type to a `SqlDateTime` rather than `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly related, I believe it is the cause: [EF Linq Error after change from dotnet Core 2.2.6 to 3.0.0](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/58074844)

---

Basically, since EF Core 3 query evaluation is no longer done client-side. This means that, if a method can not be converted to a SQL command, it throws. Looking at the code it is the `DefaultIfEmpty()` that can't be translated. **Edit:** Also multiple joins with an `into [x]` seems to be untranslatable.

You "can" load the table into memory and then use it - as the client/code is handling the data, rather than the SQL query that EF is trying to compile. However, this is loading whole tables which can be quite intensive - depending on the size.

A better solution is to work with the null value - something like the below: (*not tested*)

```cs
var users =
    (
        from u in this.MyDbContext.User
            join a in this.MyDbContext.Address
                on u.UserId equals a.UserId
            join d in this.MyDbContext.JobTitle
                on e.JobTitleId equals d.JobTitleId
        select new UserViewModel
        {
            BoardId = u.BoardId,
            UserId = u.UserId,
            LastName = u.LastName,
            FirstName = u.FirstName,
            JobTitleId = u.JobTitleId,
            JobTitle = d.JobTitleDescription,
            Email = u.Email,
            Grade = u.Grade,
            Title = u.Title,
            StartDate = 
                ua == null
                    ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue
                    a.StartDate,
        }
    );
```

Comment: Hi  Glenn, I am confused with your solution. After playing around with the code, the error went away when I removed one of the join.

Comment: I would like to learn the best practice for EF Core how how to make multiple JOINs work with outleft join. So far, this query is slower than the old v4 EF. Thanks

Comment: Removing the `into ua` fixed my example - which is weird as it's on the join that you left in - but the error I got aligned with yours. Best practices is a whole other thing - one thing I will say is that relationships are the way to go - simplifies so much code. Also, it will always `left join` if the joining column is nullable.