# An expression tree may not contain an interpolated string handler conversion

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

After upgrading to .NET 6 and EF Core 6, the error `An expression tree may not contain an interpolated string handler conversion` occurs in some LINQ-to-SQL statements using the `.Where()` extension method. This happens when using a string interpolation expression within the lambda.

I could boil it down to this simplified example:

```cs
const string suffix = "a";
var temp = new [] {"0a","1a","2a","3b"}.AsQueryable().Where((element,count) => element == $"{count}{suffix}");
```

All the cases in my codebase I can fix by introducing a local variable containing the string interpolation and use this variable in the `.Where()` call.

But there are two questions I'd like to understand:

1. Why does this error occur at all? What are the (technical?) reasons behind so that using string interpolation in an expression tree is now forbidden?
2. Why can I still build the C# project? I've set `<TreatWarningsAsError>` to `true` and when opening a file containing such a statement, the IDE (both VS 2022 and Rider) gives me red squiggles.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Because EF Core is not able to convert string interpolation to SQL, and it has [switched](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074844/11683) from silently doing client side filtering to raising an error in case the expression cannot be converted to SQL. 2. Because it's a runtime error.

Comment: @GSerg Could you please clarify a bit more, because a) my code snippet is not using EF Core at all, just pure .NET and b) your linked SO post covers upgrading from EF Core v2.x to v3.x - but I upgraded from v3.1 to v6

Comment: I would say you have Resharper enabled in your VS. And this seems to be pure jetbrains check ATM, though it was introduced in roslyn for sometime in one of the [previews](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55114) and was disabled later.

Comment: Uh that was actually an awesome hint, @GuruStron! I will file an issue at JetBrains